# Weekly replacing string from multiple files

Tags: powershell, replace

I have to replace a certain string in multiple files every week. I was trying to simplify that process using PowerShell the line that has to be replaced is following:

```
extract_mdp_staging_error(149);
```

other files look the same but the String is different for ex.

```
extract_kdp_staging(149);
extract_zub_staging_error(149);
...
```

Is there a way to tell my script just to search for the text part in the () and replace it with a user Input? Cause I can't use hardcoded searches since next week there won't be 149 but 150 and so on.

**EDIT**
I have been using a script to replace the whole line in a file using PowerShell for another application, but I couldn't figure out how to code it, so it only replaces the part in the brackets. PowerShell Script:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources -Filter '*.sql' -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        $content = Get-Content $_.Fullname
        $content[7] = '   rel.nr sqlldr {0}' -f $releasenr
        $content | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
        }
```

And here is one of the files that in which I would need to replace the number in the () on line 2:

```
begin
extract_zdlb_staging(149);
commit;
end;
/ 
quit;
```

Comment: This should be doable using regex. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Sorry i never really worked with regex. But i posted my past powershell script and an example file that i would Need to replace. Hopefully this is what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `regex` with a positive lookahead and lookbehind:

```
$userInput = 250
$filePath = 'yourFilePath'

$content = Get-Content $filePath
$content -replace '(?<=\()(\d+)(?=\))', $userInput | Set-Content $filePath
```

**Regex:**

```
(?<=\()(\d+)(?=\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

**Edit:** 
Here the script adopted to your example:

```
$userInput = 250 # The number you want to put in the parentheses
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Extractor\Ressources -Filter '*.sql' -ErrorAction Stop | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $content = Get-Content $_.Fullname
        $content -replace '(?<=\()(\d+)(?=\))', $userInput | Set-Content $_.Fullname
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer and explaining! (You've been helping me quite a lot the last few days with my PowerShell problems). If i use the Regex it indeed only affects the numbers in the () but it doesn't insert the new number inside. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You are welcome :-). If you run my first script, doesn't it put 250 inside the parentheses?

Comment: I tried it in a complete new file and ran it as Administrator. It deletes the old number inside the parentheses but doesn't fill it with the new one.

Comment: Strange. This works fine here. Which PowerShell Version you are using?

Comment: oh my god... im sorry i just deleted all the old files and rewrote them. Apparently i misspelled something in the files... It works perfectly fine now... sorry for waisting your time.. My fault, but nevertheless thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Such weird things happen to me all the time ;-)